# Best way to create walls/rooms

Tags: modeling, texturing

Last year I started developing my first game and I am definitely still a beginner in this world.

The problem for me comes in creating my own assets outside Unreal Engine.
I’m using as much 3rd party assets as I can, but right now I’m in a moment where I need to create my own thing, a pub in this case.

I tried to create my pub in Maya and it was quite difficult for me, so I want to try in Blender this time, the community support is much better than Maya :)

[image: Pub]

I’m struggling to do this in Maya just because I don’t think I’m doing it in the right way.

For example, I put some walls together(that are basically cubes), but I’m struggling to make it perfect, the section where the walls merge for example, it’s never getting completely perfect, then when I export to Unreal Engine I see light leaking everywhere.

This is an early draft of my pub, I created some objects to mimic the tables and chairs just so I can feel the space, it will be removed later, but the walls should be the final ones.

How should I make this? In Blender, should I create each wall as a cube indeed? Or maybe using a plane would be better? How can I make all the walls as one object only, instead of many different cubs/planes ?

Also, when it comes to texture, as the texture inside will be different from the oustside, should I use 2 cubes or just use 1 cube with different UV mappings ?

Can someone shed some light to this poor beginner here ? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to build something like that, I would start with a plane and then delete all but one vertex.

Then I would extrude an edge long enough to match the thickness of the wall.

Then I would extrude the edge to make a wall.  At a corner, I would have extruded so that the inside edge matched the inside corner.  Next I would move the outside edge the thickness of the wall and extrude the diagonal edge in the opposite direction.

Repeat until you have the floor plan of your walls.  See below for how to make a T junction.

Select the whole floor plan and extrude it perpendicular to create the walls.

### starting out

Here's a step by step example of getting past the first corner, assuming a .2 unit thick wall.

Add a plane:

[image]

Delete all but one vertex.  (nothing to see, so next step)

Extrude .1 in the Y direction:

[image]

select both vertices (and thus the edge) and extrude in the X direction.  (I randomly pick 1.8m)

[image]

Move the outside vertex .2m in the same direction:

[image]

Extrude again, but at 90 degrees to the previous direction picking 1.6m for an example:

[image]

Move the outside again.  This time .4m.  Et cetera.

### Making a T junction

At some point you come to a T:

[image]

Square up the edge by moving the 'trailing' vertex.

[image]

Extrude the edge by the thickness of the wall:

[image]

Pick edges an extrude to create the T walls:

[image]

### Finally: Extrude the walls

Here's your final floor plan; except out of proportion:

[image]

Select everything and extrude perpendicular by the height of a wall:

[image]

Adjusting the floor plan:

Before you extrude for height you can select subsets of vertices and move them around to fix the proportions of your floorplan.

Comment: WOW!
You are the GOAT sir, thanks a lot, that step by step will help me so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope this helps you make many game assets.

Answer (score 4):

You could usr the [arcimesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/archimesh.html) add on. Draw a floor plan and let it make walls for you

Comment: I read about arcimesh, sounds nice, I'll try, thanks!